# How to efficiently fill a time series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, data-science

My general problem is that I have a dataframe where columns correspond to feature values. There is also a date column in the dataframe. Each feature column may have missing NaN values. I want to fill a column with some fill logic such as "fill_mean" or "fill zero".

But I do not want to just apply the fill logic to the whole column because if one of the earlier values is a NaN, I do not want the average i fill for this specific NaN to be tainted by what the average was later on, when the model should have no knowledge about. Essentially it's the common problem of not leaking information about the future to your model - specifically when trying to fill my time series.

Anyway, I have simplified my problem to a few lines of code. This is my simplified attempt at the above general problem:

```
#assume ts_values is a time series where the first value in the list is the oldest value and the last value in the list is the most recent.
ts_values = [17.0, np.NaN, 12.0, np.NaN, 18.0]
nan_inds = np.argwhere(np.isnan(ts_values))
for nan_ind in nan_inds:
    nan_ind_value = nan_ind[0]
    ts_values[nan_ind_value] = np.mean(ts_values[0:nan_ind_value])
```

The output of the above script is:

```
[17.0, 17.0, 12.0, 15.333333333333334, 18.0]
```

which is exactly what I would expect.

My only issue with this is that it will be linear time with respect to the number of NaNs in the data set. Is there a way to do this in constant or log time where I don't iterate through the nan index values.

Comment: I think you can not do it without loop, and we can try to speed it up by using numba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want `nan` value replaced with a rolling mean (full window) on pandas series `s`, noting from [WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/wenyoben) that this does not continue the rolling mean calculation during the fill. (so your 15.3 becomes a 12.0).

```
s.fillna(s.expanding(1).mean())
```

If you would like the rolling mean to update as nans are filled, this in-place [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) solution may help

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def rolling_fill(a): 
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        if np.isnan(e):
            a[i] = np.mean(a[:i])

ts_values = np.array([17.0, np.NaN, 12.0, np.NaN, 18.0])
rolling_fill(ts_values)
print(ts_values)
```

which gives

```
[17.         17.         12.         15.33333333 18.        ]
```

you could probably improve this by keeping a sum and not calling `.mean` everytime.

**Time Complexity**

This is not `log` or `constant` time as you must interpolate at most `n-2` missing items from an array of length `n` which is `O(n)` - but it should be plenty optimized (by avoiding iteration in native python) and you can not do *theoretically* better, but lower level implementations of the above will make this dramatically faster.

---

**EDIT**: I originally misread and thought you were asking about interpolation

You would like to [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) the series, and pandas support this directly.

```
>>> s = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, 5])
>>> s
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    5.0
dtype: float64
>>> s.interpolate()
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Or if you do not want to use `pandas` because your example is an `ndarray`, then use [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) accordingly.

Comment: kind check your output .

Comment: nice catch @WeNYoBen - not sure how to resolve it without a loop. some jit may be required